# Are there examples of errors caused by the use of two English units?

Tags: failure, unit-systems

The [Mars Climate Orbiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter#Cause_of_failure) was infamously lost because of software which used metric units in some places and U.S. Customary units in other places, without conversion factors.  The incident is discussed in [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20239/26446).

**Are there any examples of space-related errors caused by two different but both English/Imperial/Customary units?**

Comment: An incident in civil aviation (not space) was the "Gimli Glider". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimli_Glider . A 767 ran out of fuel due to an error in volume-to-mass conversion. Its not clear (to me) the cause, but the investigation recommended " the immediate conversion of all Air Canada aircraft from Imperial units to metric units, since a mixed fleet was more dangerous than an all-Imperial or an all-metric fleet."